# Which OpenGL ES Version is most compatible with OpenGL 3.3?

Tags: opengl, version

I would like to build a cross platform OpenGL program using 3.3 on windows and linux.
I would also like to port it to android, although I'm not sure which ES version is most compatible with 3.

Answer (score 0):

With my experience it's OpenGL ES 2.0.

Only one thing, I wrote small shader parser which is doing transformation shaders from GLSL 1.1 to 1.5.

I have heavy app which is runs on Mac, iOS and Android.

But maybe better for you to use some small engine.